# Wordpress REST API, Oauth1, and python requests not working

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-requests, wordpress-rest-api, oauth-1.0a

I am having a very odd issue that I cannot seem to solve:

I have set up the **REST API** and an **Oauth1 server** on my **wordpress site**.

I had previously been able to use the **python requests library** to connect to the server and upload new posts, however, I revisted the code 2 months later and it now doesn't work. The error response says: `b'{"code":"json_oauth1_signature_mismatch","message":"OAuth signature does not match","data":{"status":401}}'`

I can connect to the Oauth1 server and upload new posts to my site via the **Postman** HTTP request builder, so it seems that the site is not the problem.

The code cannot be the problem either as I have not changed it in the past 2 months since it was last working well. Also I have tested it on a locally hosted wordpress installation and it works fine.

A stripped down version of the code looks like this:

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

OAuth_credentials = {
'client_key': 'X',
'client_secret': 'X',
'resource_owner_key': 'X',
'resource_owner_secret': 'X'
}

auth = OAuth1(*OAuth_credentials.values())

headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
}

data = {
    'title': 'title'
}

response = requests.request(
    'POST',
    'https://www.X.com/wp-json/WP/v2/posts/',
    headers=headers,
    auth=auth,
    json = data
)
```

It seems so strange to me that Postman is working but the python requests library isn't working. I can only think that I must have changed something on my site such as htaccess, but I have had no luck with that line of enquiry.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN HTTPS Redirection Plugin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [E=X-HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [E=X-HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS Redirection Plugin


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this now. I found that for some reason wordpress didn't like the requests user-agent in the http request. I change it and now it works.